# How do you ask a user to fill an array without using a scanner?

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

I'm doing a lab for class and I can't figure out how to fill an array of 10 with user input using JOptionPane. We have not learned about scanners and would prefer not to use one.

Comment: All these courses that introduce complexity only to avoid the scary CLI monster...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JOptionpane and can use the input text boxes all you would have to do is use the split method to take the input and split it into an array. I would need to see the code you currently have to give the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 10 strings, separated by commas.");
String[] inputArray = input.split(",");
```

That doesn't work if you want commas in your array elements though.  To get around that, you could try this, but it's a bit more clunky:

```
String inputArray[] = new String[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    inputArray[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an array element " + i);
}
```

`inputArray` is your final filled array of 10.